# Kubernetes Failed to create object: Namespace is required for v1.Endpoints

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I'm  currently trying to setup heketi on kubernetes, i need to create an endpoint like so (i'm using Ansible):

```
- hosts: 'masters'
  remote_user: kube
  become: yes
  become_user: kube
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
  tasks:
    - name: "Create gluster endpoints on kubernetes master"
      kubernetes.core.k8s:
        state: present
        definition:
          apiVersion: v1
          kind: Endpoints
          metadata:
            name: glusterfs-cluster
            labels:
              storage.k8s.io/name: glusterfs
              storage.k8s.io/part-of: mine
              storage.k8s.io/created-by: username
          subsets:
            - addresses:
                - ip: 10.0.0.4
                  hostname: gluster1
                - ip: 10.0.0.5
                  hostname: gluster2
                - ip: 10.0.0.6
                  hostname: gluster3
                - ip: 10.0.0.7
                  hostname: gluster4
              ports:
                - port: 1
```

When i run ansible playbook on this i am getting this error:

> Failed to create object: Namespace is required for v1.Endpoints

I can't find any information as to what it's talking about, what is the namespace supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `Endpoints` resource (like a `Pod`, `Service`, `Deployment`, etc) is a *namespaced* resource: it cannot be created globally; it must be created inside a specific [namespace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/).

We can't answer the question, "what is the namespace supposed to be?", because generally this will be something like "the same namespace as the resources that will rely on this `Endpoints` resource".

Comment: thankyou, i actually figured it out before i saw your answer, but i've marked you as correct